# What happens when a flying sword is killed?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, weapons, animated-objects

In 5e there's a monster called a [flying sword](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/flying-sword) (it's a Small construct). When it is killed, what happens?

- Does the sword break?
- Does it lose its magic and revert to a mundane sword that a character could use as a weapon?
- Does it disappear?
- Does it become inactive for some period of time and eventually regain its magic to continue bothering adventurers?
- Something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The MM page 19 has this to say about [animated objects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-a#AnimatedObjects):

> The magic that animates an object is dispelled when the construct drops to 0 hit points. An animated object reduced to 0 hit points becomes inanimate and is too damaged to be of much use or value to anyone.

A Flying Sword is an animated object so this means that when it dies, although it does not disappear it can't really be used for much. Since the magic that animates it is dispelled, it also does not continue to pester anyone.

Comment: I wonder what'd happen if you tried melting it as scrap? :P

Comment: You'd get a lump of scrap metal. The animating magic goes away at 0 hp, after that it's just a beat up sword.